# How to launch an android application in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

So I've done the "Hello, World" tutorial on the android developer site. Instructions on how to launch the application:

1) Select Run > Run.
2) Select "Android Application".

Simple enough. Except what starts is the android default launcher, not the application. How do I get the actual application to start?

Code is a copy paste from: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

**Edit**: Haven't tried logcat yet, but the console gives me:

```
[2011-08-23 15:57:19 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-08-23 15:57:19 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-08-23 15:57:19 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-08-23 15:57:19 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MyPhone'
[2011-08-23 15:57:19 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MyPhone'
```

**Edit2**: Apparently this is a known problem. The solution provided by google doesn't work for me, but might for someone else: http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/troubleshooting.html#eclipse

**Edit3**: I've found numerous people with the same problem, but no solutions so far. **Workaround**: use a physical device. The program runs fine on my Nexus One. I'm leaving the question for now, can't spend more time on this.

Comment: What do you see in the console and logcat windows?

Comment: Seems weird, cause the steps described above are absolutely right.

Comment: can you see your application's icon and name on the emulator?

Comment: close your all emulator. then go to Project->Run->Run as -> Android Application. it will launch the emulator automatically.

Comment: What is your environment? Windows? Can you start an emulator without launching any app?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit. Emulator starts fine without running an app.

Answer (score 0):

Right click to your `project -> Run As -> Android Application`

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and select `Run -> Run as -> Android Application`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it doesn't start the application. You can launch the menu and you would see your application installed there. You can then manually launch the application.

Sometimes trying to run the application multiple times from Eclipse as well helps!

Comment: Hmm, sorry I'm not following. How do I launch the application manually? From the android application menu "inside the emulated phone"? Can't see it there unfortunately.

Comment: If you can't see the application in the menu, then it did not get installed. Run your application again and check the console window. Does it say that the application was installed?

Answer (score 0):

- **This may happen if another project (even a non Android project) is selected in your Eclipse workspace tree.**

In that case, the Run command will be applied to this project even if a source file of HelloWord is opened on the edition screen.

Ensure that a source file of HelloWorld, or the project HelloWorld itself, is selected.

- **Or you may just need to unlock the Emulator that started.**

When running the app from Eclipse, an emulator is started. But it appears locked. You have to unlock it to make the keyguard to disappear, as if it was an actual cellphone.

Comment: Hello world is selected in the package explorer. I've even tried right clicking the package > run as > android application. The emulator is unlocked. :)

Comment: Well, that's strange! I have no other idea I confess :///

Comment: As always in these situations it's probably something incredibly simple. :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please let us know once found :)